# Constructor on type 'UIKit.UISwipeGestureRecognizer' not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

i have a project that i downloaded it from tfs and i don't have any idea about it but when I tried to access a specific page, this error occurred :

```
Unhandled Exception:  System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'UIKit.UISwipeGestureRecognizer' not found. occurred
```

only on xamarin.ios project (project is xamarin forms)
any idea how to fix it.

Comment: Have you search the iOS project for any custom UISwipeGestureRecognizer classes?

Comment: i dont't know if you mean this :  there a folder Gestures contain : BaseNativeGestureRecognizer.cs , NativeGestureRecognizerFactory.cs, NativeLongPressGestureRecognizer.cs, NativePanGestureRecognizer, NativePinchGestureRecognizer, NativeSwipeGestureRecognizer.cs, NativeTapGestureRecognizer.cs

Comment: it's not github sorry, i got the project from tfs , it's exclusive project for a company that i worked with it

Comment: Could you share the code in those Gestures ?